# Deserialize JSON object in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

I have a class `Rest` for calling a rest service and a class `mainpage` for login with user/password. in the `Rest` class I put the JSON result in a `var Final`.

My problem is I need to Deserialize the JSON

in the JSON result i have a class Data  ---> "data":{"real_response_LDAP":"n","response":"y"}
and I need to test in the `mainpage` for login if response ="y" or response "n"

My Rest code is:

```
    //...

    var Final = response.Content;

    Console.WriteLine("Response Finall: " + Final);
    Product test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(Final);


    return token;

}

public class Product
{

    public class InfoUser
    {
        public string service { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParamsUser
    {
        public string year { get; set; }
        public InfoUser Params { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public string service { get; set; }
        public int row_count { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public ParamsUser Params { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public static string real_response_LDAP { get; set; }
        public static string response { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }

    }
```

Main Page code:

```
String real_response_LDAP_STR;
real_response_LDAP_STR = Product.Data.response;
Console.WriteLine("lstInstagramObjects.response --->: " + Product.Data.response);


if (Product.Data.real_response_LDAP != null && real_response_LDAP_STR =="y" )
{

    await DisplayAlert("login", "Login Success.", "Ok");
    ActivitySpinner.IsVisible = false;
    // App.RestService.Login(user);
    // App.UserDatabase.SaveUser(user);
    // App.TokenDatabase.SaveToken(result);
    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetail());

    }
    else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MasterDetail()));
    }
```

Comment: I tried formatting your post to make it a little more readable. Some of the phrasing is still a little confusing. Try to [edit] the post to make the problem more clear.

Comment: What i understood so far is you are trying to deserialize a Json string am i correct?

Comment: M.@Nkosi i edit my post   yes M.@G.hakim i'm trying to deserialize a json string

Comment: What is the problem you're having?  Is the string not deserializing correctly?  Do you get an error or exception?

Comment: i don't get any error but the Product.Data.response is empty

Comment: in the code you posted, `test` is the object you are deserializing into, not `Product`

Comment: @Jason what is the exact commande line ,

Comment: Have you tried verifying that the serialized json in fact matches your model.  You can do that at https://app.quicktype.io